# How cast a LPARAM to a Structure in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I need help to cast a `LPARAM` type to **Structure**. For example, in C++ we have:

```cpp
struct MyStructure
{
   int data01;
   int data02;
};

BOOL CALLBACK CallbackProc(int number, LPARAM param)
{
   MyStructure *myStruct = (MyStructure *) param;
}
```

And in Delphi i tried this, but compiler give error of *incompatible types* on highlighted line with a comment:

```pascal
type
  TMyStructure = record
    data01: Integer;
    data02: Integer;
  end;

PMyStructure = ^TMyStructure;

function CallbackProc(number: Integer; param: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  myStruct: TMyStructure;
begin
  myStruct := param; // How stays here?
end;
```

Comment: It's a pointer to the structure. Cast it to PMyStructure.

Comment: But how? `myStruct := (PMyStructure)param` not works.

Comment: Of course not. You can't assign a pointer to T to a variable of type T. You need to dereference the pointer usinv the `^` operator. I suggest you refresh you memory on pointer syntax in the documentation.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Variable_Typecasts http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pointers_and_Pointer_Types_(Delphi)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ code is casting the `LPARAM` to a *pointer* to a struct. In Delphi, that would look like this:

```
type
  TMyStructure = record
    data01: Integer;
    data02: Integer;
  end;
  PMyStructure = ^TMyStructure;

function CallbackProc(number: Integer; param: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  myStruct: PMyStructure;
begin
  myStruct := PMyStructure(param);
end;
```

Comment: Or: `var myStruct: TMyStructure; begin myStruct := PMyStructure(LPARAM)^; end;`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis yes, but that makes a *copy* of the struct data, whereas using a pointer allows you to work with the *original* data directly.

Comment: sometimes you want a copy.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, to acess each data of structure based in your solution what is right? this way: `myStruct.data01` and `myStruct.data02` **OR** `myStruct^.data01` and `myStruct^.data02`? What is the diference between `.` and `^.`?

Comment: @BrowJr in Delphi, when [Extended Syntax](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Extended_syntax_(Delphi)) is enabled (which it is by default), both syntaxes are accepted by the compiler when accessing a member via a pointer. The `^` to dereference a pointer is optional. So both ways are correct, there is no difference. The compiler produces the same machine code in both cases.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, OK, thank you by this explanation and solution of answer.

Comment: @BrowJr It's well worth reading the documentation. You'll find it makes you more knowledge and able to work these problems out for yourself.